# Values from Express request query (query string) is percent-encoded

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express for my API. When I send request like this:

```
http://localhost/resource?offer=20% discount
```

This is what `request.query` looks like:

```
{ badge: '20%%20discount' }
```

I tried to decode it using `decodeURIComponent` but it threw exception `URIError: URI malformed`.

Is there any way I can get exact passed string like `"20% discount"`?

Edit:

I installed `qs` and `urlencode` As I'm investigating the problem a little bit (since these are the libraries `express` is using under the hood to parse the URL) I wonder why browsers don't percent-encode the percent sign?? When I send `?offer=20%25%20discount` express parses it correctly.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) ( `%` => `%25` )

Comment: What's encoding the URL to start with? That _is_ malformed, it should be `20%25%20discount`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah you're right. The string in req.query.offer is actually not supposed to be URL encoded... but it seems like a bug with this kind of string I provided!